# Ruby nokogiri parsing Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am parsing a webpage using the following code:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
links = @doc.css("span[class='reviewCount']").css('a')
links.each do |link| 
  link["href"]
end
```

I get a list of href reference as follows

```
/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d719052-Reviews-Epicure-City_Ile_de_France.html#REVIEWS
/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d6958622-Reviews-Seb_on-City_Ile_de_France.html#REVIEWS
/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d8766885-Reviews-Le_cherine-City_Ile_de_France.html#REVIEWS
```

I am trying to get the substring between Reviews- and -City

```
Epicure
Seb_on
Le_cherine
```

by replacing

```
  link["href"]
```

by

```
  link["href"][[/\"Reviews-"(.*?)"-City"/, 1]
```

but I do not manage to find the right syntax. Could anyone help me to find correct syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/Reviews-((.)+)-City/` is the regexp to extract "WHATIWANT" from "XX-Reviews-WHATIWANT-City-XX"

```
 "XX-Reviews-WHATIWANT-City"[/Reviews-((.)+)-City/, 1]
 #=> "WHATIWANT"
```

Full solution:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = <<-EOF
<span class="reviewCount">
<a href="XX-Reviews-WHATIWANT-City-XX" target="_blank" onclick="XX;">1,361 reviews</a>
</span>
EOF

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.xpath("//span[@class='reviewCount']/a").each do |node|
  puts node.attribute("href").to_s[/Reviews-((.)+)-City/, 1]
end
```

Comment: Thanks but the reason I put XX is because those are dynamic and keep changing. Only "Reviews-" and "-City" remain the same for all href I am parsing. Is there a way I can use \w without specifying the number of bytes?

Comment: Thanks and apology I believe the question was not detailed enough. I have put some examples of some the full hrefs I am trying to parse. The number of bytes before the substring I am trying to retrieve can change so I am not sure that \w{7} will always work.

Comment: @Bastien I hope now I understood everything correctly

Comment: Thank you. I just tried this thanks to your suggestions [/Reviews-((.)+)-\w{4}/, 1] and it works.